# Displaying queue array elements

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I am having trouble displaying the elements in the queue array. I am able to display the details of the queue array, but not the actual elements. How can I print the elements in the queue array?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Queue {

    private int max, front, back, num;
    private int [] qarray;

    //Constructor
    public Queue (int q) {
        max = q;
        qarray = new int [max];
        front = 0; back = -1; num = 0;
    }

    //Insert
    public void insert(int add) {
        if(back >= max -1) back = -1;
        qarray [++back] = add; num++;
        System.out.println("INSERT " + add + " Was Added to the Queue\n");

    }


    public void display() {
        System.out.println("In The Queue: ");
        System.out.println("Max: " + max + ". Front Index: " + front + ". Back Index: " + back
                + ". Index's Occupied: " +num + "\n");

    }

     //PRINT ARRAY METHOD
    public static void printArray(int[] A) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Queue theQ = new Queue(10);

        theQ.insert(11);
        theQ.insert(15);
        theQ.insert(7);
        theQ.display();
        theQ.printArray(A);
```

Comment: You need to iterate the array and print the elements one by one.

Comment: The code shown will not compile. Looking at the `main`-method: What is `A` in `theQ.printArray(A);`? There is nowhere an `A` defined. You probably want to print the elements of `theQ`. Then remove the parameter `int[] A` from the method `printArray` and let the loop print the elements of `qarray` instead of (now) `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `printArray` function as shown below:

```
public static void printArray() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < qarray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(qarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, in `main()` use `theQ.printArray()`.

you are passing `array A` in the `main()` and you haven't declared it, so you should be getting a compile error